# sbt-assembly: Create jar for a single project of a multi-project build

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a multi-project build.sbt file. I would like to assemble the jar for just one of the projects. Currently, I do the following:

$ sbt

> project analysis
>   assembly
>   ...
>   exit

I would like to save a few steps and assemble the jar for the project "analysis" from the command line. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use sbt without its REPL:

```
$ sbt analysis/assembly
```